# Return one instance of duplicate object values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, get

I'm returning information from a [large API](http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule/full) which contains duplicate object values. I have an array of program names and a function that finds an retrieves the titles I want. However, I only want them returned once rather than multiple times.

```
//...
var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
const lateNightHosts = ['The Late Show with Stephen Colbert', 'Conan', 'Jimmy Kimmel Live'];

for (x in data){
  let title = data[x]._embedded.show.name;

  function getShow() 
    if (lateNightHosts.indexOf(title) !== -1){
      console.log(title)
    } 
  }

  getShow()
}
```

The API is large due to future schedules, so `console.log` returns the title multiple times. I'd like to return it once. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of `data`

Comment: In the function `getShow(array)`, `array` is never used. What's it supposed to be for?

Comment: @Eddie I just updated with a link, you can also see it [here](http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule/full)

Comment: @kshetline My mistake. That was from a previous attempt to solve this, I've removed the parameter

Comment: You can use a `Set` to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
const lateNightHosts = ['The Late Show with Stephen Colbert', 'Conan', 'Jimmy Kimmel Live'];
const displayed = new Set();

for (x in data){
  let title = data[x]._embedded.show.name;

  function getShow() 
    if (lateNightHosts.indexOf(title) !== -1) {
      if (!displayed.has(title)) {
        console.log(title);
        displayed.add(title);
      }
    } 
  }

  getShow();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot

Comment: When i use `console.log()` to display results, it shows the correct values. When I try to display it to HTML, it returns as [object Set] or undefined. Any solutions for this?

Comment: `Set` objects have a `forEach` method, just like arrays. A quick-n-dirty solution to get all of the titles in string form would look something like this (sorry that comments don't have line breaks): `const titles = []; displayed.forEach(title => titles.push(title));` Then you can use `titles.join()`. If you want nice formatting, this is just a rough starting point, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all titles to array and then filter it

```js
const lateNightHosts = ['The Late Show with Stephen Colbert', 'Conan', 'Jimmy Kimmel Live', 'The Late Show with Stephen Colbert', 'Conan', 'Jimmy Kimmel Live', 'The Late Show with Stephen Colbert', 'Conan', 'Jimmy Kimmel Live', 'The Late Show with Stephen Colbert', 'Conan', 'Jimmy Kimmel Live'];

filteredArray = lateNightHosts.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return lateNightHosts.indexOf(item) == pos;
})

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Also you can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), since it contains only unique elements and then using spread operator transform it to array

```js
const lateNightHosts = ['The Late Show with Stephen Colbert', 'Conan', 'Jimmy Kimmel Live', 'The Late Show with Stephen Colbert', 'Conan', 'Jimmy Kimmel Live', 'The Late Show with Stephen Colbert', 'Conan', 'Jimmy Kimmel Live', 'The Late Show with Stephen Colbert', 'Conan', 'Jimmy Kimmel Live'];

var set = new Set(lateNightHosts);
var filteredArray = [...set];
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a great place to take advantage of the new ES6 Set data structure. The Set will only add unique values and has several functions on its prototype which allow you to access and mutate the data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

```
let store = new Set();
for (x in data){
  store.add(data[x]._embedded.show.name);
}
```

This new structure is iterable, has a size property, and several handy prototype functions like has(), delete(), and clear().

```js
let target = document.getElementById('data-target');

let set = new Set();
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    set.add(`value-${i}`);
}
let elem = '';
set.forEach((value) => {
    elem += `<div>${value}</div>`;
});

target.innerHTML = elem;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="data-target"></div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! `Set()` definitely helps. When I use `console.log()` it shows the correct values. When I display it to HTML using javascript template literals, it returns as [object Set] or undefined. Do you know of any solutions for this?

Comment: Could you give me an example of your implementation?

Comment: The updated answer actually helped out a lot. Thanks!